# Hashed Password Kerberos PKDF2 AES - ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

I know that in Active Directory environments passwords are stored in the form of hashes depending on encryption types used in the environment.

I understand also that when using AES as a symmetric encryption type, the user password goes through PKDF2 first which generates a key derived from the password, salt included.

Now my question is, when does AES come into play here? We get the key but what do we do with said key afterwards? What is it sent to the domain controller for verification? How does the domain controller before hand get the AES key to compare it with what the client sends?

If there is a different randomly generated AES key to use to encrpyt the hashed password, in what moment is it created?

Comment: Maybe see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/cng-dpapi-backup-keys-on-ad-domain-controllers  and/or this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @pcalkins even though these articles do not mention Kerberos, it looks like this is the way it works indeed. When the articles talk about backup keys, I guess it talks about the RC4 or AES keys for user's or machine's passwords that then can be used to forge Kerberos tickets. What are your thoughts though?

Comment: I know very little, but according to that link about DPAPI, the key that's used for transport is generated randomly... it's not the master key or the backup master.

Comment: "The MasterKey, however, is not used explicitly to protect the data. Instead, a symmetric session key is generated based on the MasterKey, some random data, and any additional entropy, if an application chooses to supply it. It is this session key that is used to protect the data. The session key is never stored. Instead, DPAPI stores the random data it used to generate the key in the opaque data BLOB. When the data BLOB is passed back in to DPAPI, the random data is used to re-derive the key and unprotect the data."  That's all used to encrypt/decrypt the hash.

Comment: @pcalkins yeah, I agree, still not a 100% sure if this is the way Kerberos works exactly, I am pretty sure some of it like the keys derived from passwords is used, but not so sure about master keys. I know for a fact as well that tickets are encrypted but inside of them there's a session key as well which is the symmetric key used to encrypt the data.

Comment: Cross posted and answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/109122/1172) on [crypto.se]. Scrutinization requested of the first answer as I don't trust the answerer entirely w.r.t. questions about AD :P Please don't cross post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted and has an answer on Crypto. It's a toss up as to which site this question should reside. All subsequent answers should go there.